# This assembly is not found: 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2019, .net-assembly

I have a Web Api application. When I run it, this error is shown:

`No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

That means that assembly is not found.

In web.config file, this entry exists:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Project has the reference `System.Net.Http` version 4.2.

[image]

What may be happening and how can I solve it?

I have Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I remember fighting with this in earlier versions of framework. What version are you using?

Comment: @TheGeneral .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Try to delete this binding. `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>`  Or modify to` <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />`. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the reference from project references and if you have added the reference from NUGET then remove the package from NUGET.

Remove all the entries for this file from your web.config as well

Close solution, then reopen. Clean and rebuild the solution.

add system.net.http (by microsoft) from NUGET.

these steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and solved it commenting this line in the web.config bellow the assemblyIdentity for System.Net.Http:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).